# How to change module position through its display string from omnetpp.ini?

Tags: omnet++

I have a network of several modules, one of which uses `StationaryMobility` as  mobility module. Minimal example:

```
network World {
  submodules:
    station1: station {
      @display("p=800,800;is=vl");
    }
}
```

with

```
import inet.mobility.static.StationaryMobility;

module station {
  submodules:
    mobility: StationaryMobility
    { }
}
```

`station` is a foreign module and I may not apply changes to it.

I now want to change the position of this module through changes in the `omnetpp.ini` so I can comfortably move `station1` around from run to run.

I tried parameterizing it as shown in https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:displaystring-parameter-substitution :

```
network World {
  parameters:
    posX = 800;
    posY = 800;
  submodules:
    station1: station {
      @display("p=$posX,$posY;is=vl");
    }
}
```

so I could do this in omnetpp.ini:

```
*.posX = 1600
*.posY = 2400
```

But `StationaryMobility` doesn't like it:

```
<!> Error in module (inet::StationaryMobility) scenario.station1.mobility (id=28) during network initialization: Mobility position is not a finite number after initialize (x=-nan,y=-nan,z=-nan).
```

Unfortunately I can neither find the display string which was generated nor have I found a way through manipulating `StationaryMobility` directly.

How can I change the position of `station1` from within the `omnetpp.ini`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing two things here.
The `displayString` can be used to modify the position of a module in the NED editor and the GUI, but this isn't necessarily the position that the mobility models (like `StationaryMobility`) from INET use.

Take a look at `StationaryMobility.ned` first, to find out which parameters the module has, so that you can later edit them the `omnetpp.ini` for example.

The most important parameters are:

- `double initialX`
- `double initialY`
- `double initialZ`
- `bool initFromDisplayString`

The last one (`initFromDisplayString`) enables the initial setting of the position parameters based on the `displayString` (specifically the `p` parameters in `@display("p=x,y;")` ).

If you want to substitute the display string parameters, you would need to define the X and Y position as double parameters just like [its done in the manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:displaystring-parameter-substitution). But you forgot to define the parameter type `double`, so OMNeT does not know what 1600 is (in this example).

Setting the `posX`/`posY` variables in the `omnetpp.ini` file also might require double asterisks, depending on your NED structure: [asterisk vs double asterisks](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:asterisk-vs-double-asterisk)

Getting back to the actual `StationaryMobility` model.
Instead of using the `displayString`, you can already set the initial positions directly in your `omnetpp.ini` file, just like this:

```
**.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinY = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxX = 100m  # example value
**.constraintAreaMaxY = 100m  # example value
**.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m
**.mobility.initFromDisplayString = false # ignore displayString positions
station1.mobility.initialX = 50m
station1.mobility.initialY = 50m
```

Depending on your network structure and module hierarchy, you need to adjust the path for `station1.mobility.initialX` or you can simplify it via asterisks operators.

Things like run-dependent position settings, iterations for different runs, etc are all possible in the `omnetpp.ini` then.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I can't believe I missed these options. Must have looked at the code for too long by now.

I think don't need to bother with the contraint area though. As I could look up thanks to your hint, the constraints are infinite when not initialized otherwise, which is suitable for me.